# Preciso que quando clicar em uma das opções da lista retorne o valor determinado para cada um dos cargos na caixa de total salário

Tags: javascript, html, value, html-option

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<title>Desenvolvimento de uma página para Cadastro de Funcionários de um sistema de RH</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <h1>Cadastro de Funcionário</h1>

    <hr class="hr3">

    <h2 class="nome">Seu nome</h2>
    <input id="idname" type="text" required="" name="nome" class="namebox" placeholder="nome"
        style="font-style:italic">

    <h2>Seu e-mail</h2>
    <input id="idemail" type=email required="" name=email class="emailbox" placeholder="contato@dominico"
        style="font-style:italic">

    <h2>Sua data de nascimento</h2>
    <input type="date" min="1950-01-01" max="2100-12-31" required="" name="data" class="datebox">

    <h2>Seu salário</h2>
    <input id="idsalario" type="value" required="" name="salario" class="salariobox">

    <h2 class="cargo_cad">Seu cargo</h2>

    <select id="cargo_cad" class="opcoes" name="cargo_cad" required="" onchange="adjustSalary(this.value);">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="select"> Selecione...</option>

        <option value="" selected>selecione...</option>

        <option value="gerente">Gerente</option>

        <option value="analista">Analista de Sistemas</option>

        <option value="dev">Desenvolvedor</option>

        <option value="dba">DBA</option>

    </select>

    <h2>Total salário</h2>
    <input id="idtotalsalario" class="totalsalariobox" type="text" placeholder="" disabled="">


    <br><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="myButton" class="myButton" value="Gravar">

</form>
```

{
        new function
            adjustSalary(profession) {

            var value = 0;

            switch (profession) {

                case 'gerente':
                    value = 21000.00;
                    break;

                case 'analista':
                    value = 11000.00;
                    break;

                case 'dev':
                    value = 9500.00;
                    break;

                case 'dba':
                    value = 10500.00;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }

            var salary = parseFloat(document.getElementById('salario_cad').value) + value;
            document.getElementById('salario_cad').value = salary;

        }}

Comment: O que você quer é exibir o valor digitado em seu salário + o valor selecionado no switch?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza se é isso que tu quer, mas fiz:

```
function adjustSalary(profession) {
 let totalSalary = document.getElementById('idtotalsalario');
 let value = 0;
 switch (profession) {
  case 'gerente':
   value = 21000.0;
   break;
  case 'analista':
   value = 11000.0;
   break;
  case 'dev':
   value = 9500.0;
   break;
  case 'dba':
   value = 10500.0;
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }
 var salary = parseFloat(document.getElementById('idsalario').value) + value;
 totalSalary.value = salary;
// document.getElementById('salario_cad').value = salary; 
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).